# Excluding inputs from jqTransform Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqtransform

This question was asked by another user, but didn't get an answer... so I am reposting.  I'm using the jqTransform plugin, but would like it to skip 2 text inputs that I want to hide via CSS and use as non-instrusive spam checks.  Hidden, people won't fill them out but bots will.  That sort of thing.  I can't disable them via jquery b/c I want the bots to fill them out.  And my CSS rule doesn't work b/c the plugin spits out new elements that weren't in the DOM.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `jqTransformHidden` to the element that you want the jqTransform plugin to skip.

Comment: that is far more elegant.  didn't know that existed.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out.... the plugin preserves my table structure, when it creates its new one.  So, I put a "noshow" class on the  element that contains the inputs i want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

jqtransformdone

Add the above class to any PARENT element that contains form elements. I noticed that the script looks for this value before performing any actions.